# PDFkit (Node): How to create paragraph indents?

Tags: javascript, node-pdfkit

I'm trying to create paragraph indents in PDFkit. The PDFkit docs state that the indent attribute is "to indent each paragraph of text". While trying this, only the first line has an indent.

```js
const doc = new PDFDocument({ size: "A4" });
doc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('output2.pdf'));
doc.addPage()
doc.text('fdgfdgfg fggfdgfdg fgfdg fdg dfgdfgdfg dfgfdg fgfgfdg fdgdfgdfg', { indent: 30 })
doc.end();
```

The code delivers an indent only in the first line of the paragraph. How can I indent the whole paragraph?

Comment: Well, of course in PDF not, but in the generation frameworks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to `doc.text and doc.moveDown` if you want consecutive paragraphs.

```
const doc = new PDFDocument({ size: "A4" });
doc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('output2.pdf'));
doc.addPage()
doc.text('This is the start of paragraph 1', { indent: 30 });
doc.moveDown();
doc.text('This is the start of paragraph 2', { indent: 30 });
doc.moveDown();
doc.text('This is the start of paragraph 3', { indent: 30 });
doc.end();
```

Comment: Thank you. In my understanding each doc.text should be treated as a paragraph and according to related questions PDFKit does it this way, but unfortuneatly not in my case.

Answer (score 1):

In pdfkit, the `indent` option is just for the first line. If you want to indent the entire paragraph, just set the x coordinate:

```js
const doc = new PDFDocument({ size: "A4" });
doc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('output2.pdf'));
doc.addPage()
doc.text('Regular paragraph, no indent')
doc.text('Indented Paragraph', doc.x + 30, doc.y)
doc.text('Reset x back for unindented paragraph', doc.x - 30, doc.y)
doc.end();
```

Answer (score 0):

I moved from PDFKit to pdfmake (which is based on PDFKit), which handles indents for my case way better than PDFkit itself.
For my use case it's also better since I use JSON output from my markdown lexer which can easily transformed to the input for pdfmake.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).